# shell - Removing Script Tags

Tags: shell, sed, cygwin

I am new to Stack Overflow and just started using bash. I am trying to remove Javascript from several `.htm` webpages. I have the following script:

```
find $1 -name "*.htm" > ./files
#for p in $(cat ./files)
#do
   #sed? awk?
#done
```

Within the loop I need to `sed` or `awk` each line of my file so that all Javascript is completely removed. So for example,

```
<script>//SomeJS</script>
<!--foo -->
<!--bar--><script src="cheeseburger.js"> <!--bar -->
<script type ="text/javascript>
/*
* SomeJS
*/
</script> <!-- more foo-->
```

needs to ouput:

```
<!--foo -->
<!--bar-->
<!--bar -->
<!-- more foo-->
```

so that all JS is removed. I spent hours trying to use `sed` but  and  were being clobbered after a pattern match would result in the entire line being deleted or only some of the tags were being removed.

Note: I am using Cygwin.

Comment: Your posted desired output would be the result of doing more than just removing the JS as it also removes the newline before `<!--foo -->`, converts the space before the second `<!--bar -->` to a newline, and removes the space before `<!-- more foo..>` too. Is all of that really needed?

Comment: I think your sample input is missing one `</script>`. Please fix that or clarify which `<script>` the `</script>` at the end of your input file is associated with and why.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find $1 -name "*.htm" | while IFS= read -r name; do
        tr '\n' '\001' <"$name" | sed \
            -e $'s,<script[^>]*>,\002,g' \
            -e $'s,</script>,\003,g' \
            -e $'s,\002[^\003]*\003,,g' \
            -e $'s,[\002\003],,g' \
            | tr '\001' '\n' >"$name~" && \
            mv "$name~" "$name"
done
```

@Ed Morton: he’s using ancient HTML and doesn’t close the  tag.